# Passing getClass() as a parameter to a different class

Tags: java

1) I have a class called `Utilites` that performs some string checks to make sure an "ID" conforms to a standard.

2) I wanted to pass the details of the calling class to the `Utilities` class to decide if the "ID" is correct for that type (between `Members` and `Holding`).

3) `PremiumMember` is an extended class of `Member` and passes all parameters to `Member`

4) At the moment, creating a new `PremiumMember` has the Class `java.lang.Class` instead of the expected `library.Member`

The class containing the main method to test the code

```
package library;
import lib.Utilities;
public class LibraryManagementSystem 
{
    static Member[] members = new Member[15];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        members[0] = new PremiumMember("p000001", "Mr Bill Wrong"); // Prints **Java.lang.Class**
        System.out.println(members[0].getClass());                  // Prints **library.Member**
    }
```

The class containing the constructor

```
import lib.Utilities;
public abstract class Member {

public Member(String memberID, String fullName)     // Constructor for each member
{
    memberNumber = Utilities.validateId(memberID, this.getClass()); // Makes sure that the ID conforms to all requirements
    this.fullName = fullName;   
}
```

The utilities class which checks for validity of an ID number

```
import library.Holding;
import library.Member;
public class Utilities {

public static String validateId(String checkId, Type classType)
{   
    if (classType.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() == Holding.class)
    {
        // Deal with code one way
        return "Is of Holding Class"
    }
    else if (classType.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() == Member.class)
    {
        // Deal with code another way
        return "Is of Member Class"
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(classType.getClass() + " Not of  Member/Holding class");
        return "INVALID";
    }
```

I don't understand why instantiating and supposedly going though a custom constructor returns the `Java.lang.Class` class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `getClass()` on a `java.lang.reflect.Type` - so that's just going to give you `Class.class`... Effectively, you've called `this.getClass().getClass()`, and you don't want to do that.

I suspect you want to change your `validateId` method to accept a `Class<?>` instead of a `Type`, and then just use `classType.getGenericSuperclass()` etc. (I haven't checked your logic over how you're *using* the class - let's focus on getting the right class to start with.)

Comment: Could you please explain the part `You're calling getClass() on a java.lang.reflect.Type`

Comment: @Abhishek: Well look at the code in `validateId` - the type of the `classType` parameter is `Type`, and the body of the method uses `classType.getClass()`...

Comment: That was a clear and concise response, thank you.
I've changed the parameter sent to `Utilities.ValidateId` to `this.getClass()`, and I've changed the parameter accepted to `Class<?> classType`. A `sysout` in the `ValidateId` method successfully shows `library.Member`!

Comment: @fanuch: I'm afraid I don't understand the comment there (particularly the "I feel like it is dude")... but it does sound like a different problem to look at.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, and you're far too fast at responding. I meant to ask, how do I get the child class from that parameter, then thinking on your response I realized that `classType ` IS the child class!

Comment: Thanks again for your help!